# LIKE vs CONTAINS on SQL Server, CONTAINS can't find a value in DB while LIKE can

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

When I execute this:

```
select * from users where contains(email, '"example@gmail.com*"')
```

It can't find data in database.

But when I execute this:

```
select * from users where email like 'example@gmail.com%'
```

it does.
For other records both cases work properly.

Comment: What does the matching string look like?  Please include that in the question.

Comment: Why the `"`'s in query 1?

Comment: Why the EF tag? How was this query generated?

Comment: I edited your tags. Entity Framework isn't in play here. This is about full-text search in SQL server. Also, make sure you ask a clear question. This is only an observation.

Comment: `CONTAINS` is from the **full-text search** which is **word-based** - you can't find arbitrary *fragments" of some characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look just for `example@gmail.com`, then you should use

```
contains(email, 'example@gmail.com')
```

without double quotes and star. That's why you are getting different results.

Comment: It worked) But maybe you know why it didn't work in that case.
For example, I have two values, I tried to select them both using CONTAINS(with double quotes and star) and LIKE.
One value was found by LIKE only, second by CONTAINS and LIKE.

Comment: Because you had additional characters... That is the reason

Comment: But with another value it worked successfully...

`select * from users
where contains(email,'"example@gmail.com*"')   -- didn't work`

`select * from users
where contains(email,'"example_2@gmail.com*"') -- worked`


`select * from users
where email like 'example@gmail.com%'          -- worked`

`select * from users
where email like 'example_2@gmail.com%'        -- worked`